# How to build nested HashMap in C# using LanguageExt in a most-readable way?

Tags: c#, linq, hashmap, ienumerable, language-ext

In .NET / C# I have input data of type `IEnumerable<T>` with `T` having some properties I want to use for lookups.

How can I build a two-level (maybe three-level) lookup using [LanguageExt](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) without producing hard to read code like this:

```
var items = Range(1, 1000)
            .Map(i => new 
                 {
                   Number = i, 
                   Section = (byte) (i % 10), 
                   Text = $"Number is i"
                 }); // just some test data

HashMap<byte, HashMap<int, string>> lookup 
  = toHashMap(
      from item in items
      group item.Text by (item.Section, item.Number) into gInner
      group gInner by gInner.Key.Section into gOuter
      select ( gOuter.Key, toHashMap(gOuter.Map(_ => (_.Key.Number, _.Head()))) )
    );
```

Expected output: lookup hashmap with `Section` as outer key, `Number` as inner key and `Text` as value.

I prefer solutions using LINQ syntax (maybe making it easier to combine this with transforming / filtering / ordering ...).

Comment: Could you provide input /output data description/example? It would be easier to answer your question.

Comment: Question updated. Note: `Section` and `Number` should be seen as unrelated properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Language-ext has built-in extension methods](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/blob/master/LanguageExt.Core/DataTypes/HashMap/HashMap.Extensions.cs#L23) for dealing with nested `HashMap` and `Map` types (up to four nested levels deep):

So, to lookup a type:

```
HashMap<int, HashMap<string, DateTime>> lookup = ...;

var value = lookup.Find(123, "Hello");
```

You can also add:

```
lookup = lookup.AddOrUpdate(123, "Hello", value);
```

There's also `Remove`, `MapRemoveT`, `MapT`, `FilterT`, `FilterRemoveT`, `Exists`, `ForAll`, `SetItemT`, `TrySetItemT`, and `FoldT`.

So, to answer your specific question:

```
var map = items.Fold(
            HashMap<byte, HashMap<int, string>>(), 
            (s, item) => s.AddOrUpdate(item.Section, item.Number, item.Text));
```

If you do this a lot, then you could generalise it into an extension of `Seq<(A, B, C)>`

```
public static HashMap<A, HashMap<B, C>> ToHashMap<A, B, C>(this Seq<(A, B, C)> items) =>
    items.Fold(
        HashMap<A, HashMap<B, C>>(), 
        (s, item) => s.AddOrUpdate(item.Item1, item.Item2, item.Item3));
```

I had the same requirements, that's why I added these to language-ext :)